# Google Finance ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, finance, google-finance-api

I'm trying to consume Google Finance API on a Flex Project but with no success.
I want to use the ClientLogin mode, am able to get the auth token, but then I can't seem to get information from any of the feeds!

I've tried some of the few examples I found by Googling but still can't get it to work...

Comment: Roberto can you please try to elaborate more on what works vs what does not, that is when it doesn't work what kind of failure are you getting can you edit your post to include a link to the example you're trying out or else the google search terms to get to the link if your stack overflow account won't allow links yet.

Comment: Yes shaunhusain, I am trying to use the ClientLogin authentication mode, get the auth token, but I am unable to get data from a feed...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to directly call the Google service from the Flex app because Google does not have a crossdomain.xml file. You should probably call a proxy (in PHP or something) that you call and pass the URL and token to. The proxy then calls the Google service, and returns the results to your Flex app.